# Using my USB Port only as a Power Source

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb

I have a peculiar problem of requiring usb port only for powering my wifi enabled USB powered Dongle. Hope you understand. I have some application that will work only in Wifi. But now when I connect it through wire to my laptop it uses the driver and connect to it as a wired connection. I do not want it to connect it wired but it should use only the wifi of the device. This is possible if only my port is considered to be only a power source and not an interface to the pC OS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google `USB power only cable`.  There are cables specifically made that only have connections for the power wires and not the data wires.

Comment: Can u give me specific links. So that I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/668556/set-specific-usb-ports-to-charge-only        I think this link has the more appropriate answer than the above suggested solution.

Comment: Actually this is the preferred answer style on SU, it doesn't expire.  Any links to shopping sites that I gave would be dead within months.  This question also has more than one answer, I gave the one you liked the best, you found one you like more.  that's life.  =]